# Convert character longitude/latitude into numeric

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have a dataset in R called Test with longitude latitude coordinates that now have the following format after having called str(Test):

```
    $ lat                         : chr "513.035.763.793.677"
    $ lon                         : chr "33.941.883.804.984"
```

I would like to turn these into correct lon - lat coordinates. The following doesn't work:

```
    as.numeric(Test$lat) 
    as.numeric(gsub(".", "", Test$lat)
```

I get:

[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

How can I transform them into numeric coordinates that are good to plot on a map? the correct coordinates should be lon: 3.394188 and lat: 51.30357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
as.numeric(gsub(".", "", Test$lat, fixed = TRUE))
[1] 5.130358e+14
```

Without setting `fixed = TRUE`, `gsub` was treating `"."` as a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

To then get it to the format you were looking for, you simply need to multply by `1e-13`:

```
5.130358e+14 * 1e-13
[1] 51.30358
```

Comment: Works just smooth. thnx